# creating a default variable in mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have mod_rewrite take this url:

```
mydomain.com/directory/index.php?slug=slug&year=2009
```

and make it pretty:

```
mydomain.com/directory/slug/2009/
```

Easy, but now my issue is, if someone lands at the URL without the year attached (like: mydomain.com/directory/slug/), how can I add the current year to the URL?

My current `htaccess` reads:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)?$ /directory/$1/$2/ [R]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ /directory/index.php?slug=$1&year=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using server variables:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ /directory/$1/%{TIME_YEAR}/ [R]
```

If I didn't make a mistake this should redirect url:

```
mydomain.com/directory/slug/
```

to:

```
mydomain.com/directory/slug/2009/
```

(for another 2 and half months ;) )

I think you now what to do, if you don't want redirect or `/` at the end of url :)

I tried this in similar case, and this worked fine.

Oh, and you can find list of server variables in [mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteCond). I am not sure if this will always work.